# How to set <Text> text to upper case in react native

Tags: react-native, uppercase

How to set `<Text> some text </Text>` as upper case in react native?

```
<Text style={{}}> Test </Text>
```

Need to show that `Test` as `TEST`.

Comment: `<Text style={{}}> {'Test'.toUpperCase()} </Text>`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

@Cherniv   Thanks for the answer

```
<Text style={{}}> {'Test'.toUpperCase()} </Text>
```

Comment: This is not really a solution. What if I want to animate text to uppercase?

Comment: @Michal what would text animation to upper case look like, it sounds like a super cool effect I just can't imagine it right now.

Comment: @Michal Use [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native) to do cool animations, even with text. You can create custom animations via Adobe After Effects, [Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/master/docs/gifs/Example4.gif).

Comment: This is not correct answer anymore. There is default style in React Native for text transformation. Please check my answer bellow.

Comment: It works only with hardcoded text. But in my options text taken from api with {} doesn't works.

Comment: That should work well <Link style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase'}}> {link}</Link>

Answer (score 196):

iOS textTransform support has been added to react-native in 0.56 version. Android textTransform support has been added in 0.59 version. It accepts one of these options:

- none
- uppercase
- lowercase
- capitalize

The actual [iOS commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8621d4b79731e13a0c6e397abd93c193c6219000), [Android commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3a33e75) and [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style)

Example:

```js
<View>
  <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>
    This text should be uppercased.
  </Text>
  <Text style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize'}}>
    Mixed:{' '}
    <Text style={{ textTransform: 'lowercase'}}>
      lowercase{' '}
    </Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Cool, that's works for me!

Answer (score 21):

use text transform property in your style tag

```
textTransform:'uppercase'
```

Answer (score 6):

React Native .toUpperCase() function works fine in a string but if you used the `numbers` or `other non-string data types`, it doesn't work. The `error` will have occurred.

Below Two are string properties:

```
<Text>{props.complexity.toUpperCase()}</Text>

<Text>{props.affordability.toUpperCase()}</Text>
```

Answer (score 2):

use  <Text style={{textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>Test

Answer (score 0):

I am using "**` `**" and "**${}**" referenced to the variable, this is will turn it to the string, after that by using **.toUppercase()** function.

`${todo.title}`.toUppercase() }

For example:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Todo = ({ todo }) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:<components/todo.js>:",todo)
    return (
        <article className="Todo" style={{ backgroundColor: todo.completed ? 'aqua' : '#f9a1a1' }}>
            <div className="Todo-info">
                <h3>{ typeof todo.title === "string" && `${todo.title}`.toUpperCase() }</h3>
            </div>
        </article>
    );
};

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text style={{}}> {'Test'.toUpperCase()} </Text>
```

you can right this field in react-native